# Notepad++ Add additional numbers to all lines that have numbers

Tags: numbers, notepad++, addition

Is their a way in Notepad++ to add maybe 00 to all lines that containt numbers. For example

I am working on something for a game. The population is to low so I would like to just simply add 00 behind each number size for all sizes. I don't feel like going down 1365 lines for just the USA, and do this process for other countries also. So if I could simply add 00 behind any amount of number that would be great. So size = 400 would be size = 40000, and then if their was a size = 6173 it would change to size = 617300. I was thinking about how to do this with find and replace but I have to be specific with the numbers correct? So i can only change 400s or just 6173s ext.

Thank you

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, OP is looking for a way, while editing in Notepad++, to do some sort of `s/(\d+)/\100/g` type of operation, except you'd want to come up with the correct regex that excludes digits after a decimal point, digits in the middle of a word, etc. I don't really use Notepad++ so I don't know whether it can do regex replacement.

Comment: Just place 00 behind every number in notepad. So placing 00 behind 400 would make it 40000. But I would like to place 00 behind every number on the notepad. So I cant simply use find and replace to do this because I am dealing with a lot of different numbers . Unless thier is a wildcard that represents a number place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for posting an off-site link, but maybe check here:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions

You'd want to come up with a regular expression that catches all the numbers corresponding to city populations in your data file, and do a replace on the number adding 00 to it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found that \d will find any number place. So if I find \d\d it will find two numbers like 20,40,60 so on. My problem is this:

Find and replace:
Find: \d\d
Replace: 00

Out come is that it finds let say for example 20 and replaces it to 00. The outcome I want is it finds 20 then add 00 behind it to make 2000, can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a pro on regex, but this will get the job done :

replace (\d{1,10}) with $1a00, select regular expression.

That will leave you with all numbers appended with "a00", now just replace a00 with 00 in normal mode. I know this step should be avoidable, but I got to leave home and tried a few combination which didn't work :).